# Converting from class to functional component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a TicTacToe application.
Problem occured when I tried to convert from class to func. components.

I'm familiar with setting the state variable and the function to change the state of the variable, but passing into the return... i get confused.

```
import React from "react";

class Endgame extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tied: "You guys tied",
    playerWin: "You win " + this.props.winner + " !!",
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.endgame(false);
  };
  render() {
    const { winner } = this.props;
    const { tied, playerWin } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="screen">
          <p>{winner === "Tied" ? tied : playerWin}</p>
          <button className="btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Start again?
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Endgame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easly transform this component in function component in this way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Endgame = ({ winner, endgame }) => {
  const [tied, setTied] = useState("You guys tied");
  const [playerWin, setPlayerWin] = useState("You win " + winner + " !!");
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    endgame(false);
  };
    
  return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="screen">
          <p>{winner === "Tied" ? tied : playerWin}</p>
          <button className="btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Start again?
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Endgame;
```

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks) is an intersting article that explains step by step how to convert component to funcional component.

Comment: Thank you very much kind Sir, I'll strive to do as much as possible by myself in the future, but at the moment I'm just trying to break the ice regarding RJS.

Comment: @Rookie101 I added a link to an article that helps you to transform component in finctional component. Hope this help to "break the ice" =)

Comment: I'll get to it right away Giovanni :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
const Endgame=({winner,endgame})=>{
    const [state,setState]=useState({
        tied: "You guys tied",
        playerWin: `You win ${winner} !!`,
    })
    const handleClick = () => {
        endgame(false);
    };

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="screen">
          <p>{winner === "Tied" ? state.tied : state.playerWin}</p>
          <button className="btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Start again?
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}

export default Endgame;
```

here it is converted into functional component